# Reading dialog box responses in installshield basic msi project

Tags: installshield, basic-msi

i've a dialog box SAPEnv dat has eight radio buttons enclosed under same property named SAPEnviro. what i want to do is to get that value in my installscript and set registry values according to button clicked. i used msigetproperty function but its svproperty argument everytime returns blank. while nvbuff size arguement does return a value depending on size of value being returned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Basic MSI, why do you need InstallScript at all?  Why not just use the Property set by the control in the registry table. ( [PROP] ).

Comment: act i needed to set registry info depending on the options selected and response given by user. that was little customization that was needed. never mind i managed to solve that problem. but thanks anyway.